# How do the digits 1101004800 correspond with the number 20?

Tags: logic, digital

I'm trying to learn how to modify memory locations using C++ and when messing with MineSweeper, I noticed that when the clock's value in memory was 1101004800, it was 20 seconds into the game. The digits 1101529088 correspond with 21 seconds into the game. Can someone please explain to me how to convert between those 10-digit long numbers to base-10?

Comment: 1101529088 - 1101004800 = 524288 = 2^19.  I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Could it be Ticks since some epoch? Just guessing as 41A00000 seems like a strange pointer address.

Answer (score 8):

They are using floats to represent the timer. Here is a program that converts your integers to floats:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n = 1101004800;
  int n2 = 1101529088;

  printf("%f\n", *((float*)&n));
  printf("%f\n", *((float*)&n2));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20.000000
21.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

`1101004800` decimal is `0x41A00000` hex, which is the IEEE-754 representation of `20.0`.  `1101529088` decimal is `0x41A80000` hex, which is the IEEE-754 representation of `21.0`.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it sort of strange to use a float for a counter that is always integers?

Comment: That does seem kinda odd, but there may be a good reason for it.